# Binding parameters for WHERE IN clause with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My code:

```
$myArray = implode($myArray, ',');
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE ids IN (:ids)');
$sth->bindParam(':ids', $myArray);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch();
echo $sth->rowCount();
```

Always shows a count of 1, but when I skip the parametrization and just add the variable itself in it's place, I get an accurate count. What's going on here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't bind a parameter for the IN clause like that. The $myArray string will only count as one value, like if you did this:

```
SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE ids IN ('1,2,3')
```

Even though there are three comma delimited values, the database reads them as only one string value.

You need to manually insert the IN list into the query, the old-school way.

```
'SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE ids IN (' . $myArray .')'
```

There is unfortunately no other way. At least for now.

Comment: Seriously? Prepared statements can't handle that? How lame is that :/

Comment: @hoppa: they can handle it like this: `id IN (:id1, :id2, :id3...)`, you get the pattern. You're better off with the oldschool method.

Comment: This question confirms it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition

Comment: @Jared, I guess my question is a duplicate then. Should've searched more :(

Comment: No worries, that question was from 2009 anyway. For all you know PDO might have patched in support for this. I wouldn't consider it a duplicate considering the age of the other question :)

Comment: Yes you can do it, just use array_fill to make an array of parameter length with ? and implode it into the query

Comment: Remember it's just a string.. its up to you to build it correctly

Answer (score 11):

I know this question is old, but this works for me:

```
$arrayOfValues = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$questionMarks = join(",", array_pad(array(), count($arrayOfValues), "?"));
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("update some_table set end_date = today where value_no in ($questionMarks)");
$stmt->execute($arrayOfValues);
```

Answer (score -2):

You simply need a string with as many question marks as you have parameters for your in clause...   easily possible

```
    <?php 
        
        $sql = "select * from something where id in (".implode(",", array_fill(0, count($parameters), "?")).")";
    
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
        
        $sth->execute( $parameters);
        
        ?>
```