# Remove not found word from mySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

I am trying to make search and need to remove word from query, that do not have match.

Lets say there is 3 words: **one**, **two** and **three**. If one is not found, then I need to rerun query with other two words (I get result Where `empty_space` AND `two` AND `three`, so query finds nothing). And so on. But I don't know how to identify unmatched word and run query again with other two words.

EDIT: If I use this code, to count elements in array with `$i++`, query - `one two three`:

```
if(!empty($d)) {
     if($i < 2) {
      $like_str .= " (title LIKE '%".$keyword."%')";
     } else {
      $like_str .= " AND (title LIKE '%".$keyword."%')";
     }
    }
```

Result: `SELECT * FROM shop_products_ WHERE AND (title LIKE '%two%') AND (title LIKE '%three%')`

And with words that exist, query - `one two`

```
if(!empty($d)) {
     if($key < 1) {
      $like_str .= " (title LIKE '%".$keyword."%')";
     } else {
      $like_str .= " AND (title LIKE '%".$keyword."%')";
     }
    }
```

Result: `SELECT * FROM shop_products_ WHERE (title LIKE '%one%') AND (title LIKE '%two%')`

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data, desired results, and the query you are now using.

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't `AND` the constraints but `OR` them. Any unmatched word will not interfere with the others, like this:

```
WHERE w = 'one' OR w = 'two' OR w = 'three'
```

If `one` does not exist, it will be identical to:

```
WHERE w = 'two' OR w = 'three'
```

Anyways, I'd recommend to **NOT** paste your SQL query out of strings in PHP, this is very much subject to SQL-injection and a totally abandoned and discouraged practice. What you should use are parameters, depending on the actual implementation (mysqli? PDO?) similar to this:

```
WHERE w = ? OR w = ? OR w = ?
```

On the other hand, if you need an [arity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) of *n*, you may want to use the `IN` clause:

```
WHERE w IN ('one', 'two', 'three')
```

But here you can't use parameters because of technical constraints. More about it here: [Binding parameters for WHERE IN clause with PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044144/binding-parameters-for-where-in-clause-with-pdo)

Answer (score 0):

Try to make an array with words that are found, like:

```
$a = array('two','three');
```

and then implode it with " AND ".

```
$matches  = implode(" AND ", $a);
```