# Get tags from the database using SQL's IN from a comma separated string, converted to an array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, pdo

I want to get data from the selected ID number to get the photos with those tags. Here's the string I want to use: `10,3,12`. But as it is now, I'm getting the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''10,3' ORDER BY p.datetime_taken DESC' at line 7' in
```

Here's the code I am using:

```
$tags = explode(',', $_GET['tg']);
foreach($tags AS $tag) {
    $tag = $tag;
}

$in = implode(',', $tags);


# DATABAS (hämta)
$get_photos = sql("SELECT *
                   FROM photos AS p
                   JOIN tags_photos AS tp
                   ON tp.id_photo = p.id
                   JOIN tags_names AS tn
                   ON tp.id_tag = tn.id
                   WHERE tn.id IN :idtag
                   ORDER BY p.datetime_taken DESC
                  ", Array('idtag' => $in));


# FOTOGRAFIER
foreach($get_photos AS $photo) {
    echo $photo['data_file_name'];
}
```

`$_GET['tg']` contains `10,3,12`.

How can I fix this error and get the data I need from the database?

**UPDATE**
The code looks like this now:

```
$tags = str_replace(',', '?,', $_GET['tg']);

# DATABAS (hämta)
$get_photos = sql("SELECT *
                   FROM photos AS p
                   JOIN tags_photos AS tp
                   ON tp.id_photo = p.id
                   JOIN tags_names AS tn
                   ON tp.id_tag = tn.id
                   WHERE tn.id IN(:idtag)
                   ORDER BY p.datetime_taken DESC
                  ", Array('idtag' => $tags));
```

With this code, the photos getting replaced if I choose a tag before the selected one. But when I choose a tag after the selected tag, nothing happens (except for the loading part).

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Using PDO with IN clause array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767530/php-using-pdo-with-in-clause-array)

Comment: I think at the very least you need parentheses around `:idtag`: `WHERE tn.id IN (:idtag)`

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks but it didn't work :/ I got the same error, even if I replaced `'idtag' => $in` with `'idtag' => '?10,3,12'`, just for testing.

Comment: See PDO WIKI [**HERE**](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) for how to use `IN` with PDO

Comment: @davidstrachan Thank you for the link. Now when I can think straight, I can understand `IN()` better. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it (finally) to work, thanks to [Atli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7044270/718990)! Here's the solution:

```
$tags = $_GET['tg'];

# DATABAS (hämta)
$get_photos = sql("SELECT *
                   FROM photos AS p
                   JOIN tags_photos AS tp
                   ON tp.id_photo = p.id
                   JOIN tags_names AS tn
                   ON tp.id_tag = tn.id
                   WHERE tn.id IN(".$tags.")
                   ORDER BY p.datetime_taken DESC
                  ", Array());
```