# MySQL PDO "NOT IN" statement returning wrong count

Tags: php, mysql, list, pdo, notin

I'm trying to return the members who's ID's aren't on the list provided in the MySql statement.

**Heres the members table:**

```
--------------------
| ID | Member Name |
--------------------
|  1 | John Smith  |
--------------------
|  2 | Larry Brown |
--------------------
|  3 | Jim Gray    |
--------------------
```

**Here is my query statement:**

```
$entries[':list'] = "1,2,3";
$mQuery = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE ID NOT IN (:list)");
$mQuery->execute($entries);
$mTotal = $mQuery->rowCount();
```

$mTotal should be returning 0 but instead is returning 3. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: dont you have to pass in second parameter with the object to prepare

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php You can pass in a second param but its optional not required. Are you suggesting I should?

Comment: surely this should be `$entries[':list'] = "1,2,3";`

Comment: @RamRaider you're right, but still have the same results.

Comment: see [binding-parameters-for-where-in-clause-with-pdo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044144/binding-parameters-for-where-in-clause-with-pdo#answer-7044270)

Comment: @amdixion that was it! Thanks so much. Do you want to answer the question with your comment so I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: it's a duplicate and was closed as such. additional answers to duplicates shouldn't be submitted, that's basically how Stack rolls.