# How to do pdo prepared statements with multiple options for the same field?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I need to query the data base for multiple options for the same field in the where clause.

Example:

```
select * from table where (name='john' or name='phil' or name='ann')
```

For one selection I would write:

```
select * from table where name='john'
```

How would you do it for the multiple options? (name='john' or name='phil' or name='ann')

Comment: `WHERE name IN (?)`

Comment: I would use `IN` here.  Such as: `where name in ('john', 'phil', 'ann')`.

Comment: how would you bind them? "name in ( :namelist )" ???

Comment: @Calvin please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044144/binding-parameters-for-where-in-clause-with-pdo/7044270  You cannot bind a list in a single bind